# read until certain character using for loop

Tags: c++

how to read the 1st column value (name, name2 and name3) using substr function?

```
name;adress;item;others;
name2;adress;item;others;
name3;adress;item;others;
```

I've wrote

```
  cout << "Read data.." << endl;
    if (dataFile.is_open()) {
        i=-1;
        while (dataFile.good()) {
            getline (dataFile, line);
            if (i>=0) patient[i] = line;
            i++;
        }
        dataFile.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::fstream f("file.txt");
    if(f)
    {
        std::string line;
        std::vector<std::string> names;
        while(std::getline(f, line))
        {
            size_t pos = line.find(';');
            if(pos != std::string::npos)
            {
                names.push_back(line.substr(0, pos));
            }
        }

        for(size_t i = 0; i < names.size(); ++i)
        {
            std::cout << names[i] << "\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
int pos = s.find(';');
if (pos == string::npos) ... // Do something here - ';' is not found
string res = s.substr(0, pos);
```

You need to find the position of the first `';'`, and then take `substr` from zero to that position. Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/TCifSJ).

Comment: read every line 1st? why don't catch the new line and select the 1st ;?

Comment: @BernardoBaalen That would be slower. In addition, `getline` removes all the newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the rest of the line after the content before the first semicolon is read:

> ```
> std::vector<std::string> patient;
>
> std::string line;
> while (std::getline(file, line, ';'))
> {
>     patient.push_back(line);
>     file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
> }
> ```